# Block Hide Scroll Bar When Modal Show In Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to build my layout. When I show my modal, it makes my scroll bar disappear (blue rectangle on right side). I don't want to hide the scroll bar. How do I keep my scrollbar always visible?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: On your modal div that has the black rgba you have `overflow: hidden`. Modify it to `overflow: auto`. This is a guess because you didn't show any of your code.

Comment: So...what class i can change?

Comment: I don't know. You didn't show us any relevant code.

Comment: Why do you want to show the scroll bar when the modal's open? Surely you want the users' focus on the modal, why would they scrolling in the background?

Answer (score 3):

Add class `override-modal-open` to `body` like:

`<body class="override-modal-open">`

If you want the **modal scrollbar** to be visible add to your CSS file:

```
.override-modal-open.modal-open .modal {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If you want the **body scrollbar** to be visible add to your CSS file:

```
.override-modal-open {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```